# Pandas - filter data that are in last n month using query

Tags: python, pandas, datetime, filter

I want to filter my data frame based on `time` column using **query** function and get rows with `time` in last `N` month(or any time periods).

Basically I need something like:

```
df = df.query("time.isin(timeperiod('5M'))")
```

or

```
df = df.query("now() >= time >= now() - timeperiod('5M')")
```

I'm trying to create query patterns for my filter functions and It's important to use 
[query()](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.DataFrame.query.html) function.

Note that `timeperiod()` and `now()` functions are not available and I used them for better understanding of the solution I want.I mean please define these functions in your solution.

Sample:

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['time1'] = pd.date_range('1/1/2019', periods=1000, freq='D')
df['time2'] = pd.date_range('1/1/2018', periods=1000, freq='D')
```

Sample data can have some other columns.

I need to filter data to get records within last `N` month for each of given columns using `query()` function. For example I want records with `time1` in last 2 months and `time2` in last 3 months. Like getting records of people who were hired during last 3 month and were let go during last 2 months.

**UPDATE 1:**

thanks to [@jezrael](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2901002) I could get `now()` function in `query()` like this:

```
df = df.query("@pd.Timestamp('now') >= time")
```

of course `Timestamp` could be replaced by 'to_datetime` or something else.

But the problem is when I try to get a timestamp for the start of period like this:

```
df = df.query("time >= (@pd.Timestamp('now') + @pd.to_timedelta('30day'))")
```

I get:
`Cannot convert input ... of type <class 'pandas._libs.tslibs.timedeltas.Timedelta'> to Timestamp`

Again using DateOffset or other time-delta functions result with the similar error.

But using **variables** to set target date (as [@jezrael](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/users/2901002) mentioned) works.

I will use **variables** as I don't see any other way right now but I will keep this Question open to see if there is any better way.

Answer (score 7):

Use [`DateOffset`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.tseries.offsets.DateOffset.html) for last `N` months, both conditions are chained by `|` for bitwise `OR`:

```
now = pd.to_datetime('now')
last2 = now - pd.DateOffset(months=2)
last3 = now - pd.DateOffset(months=3)

df = df.query("(@now >= time1 >= @last2) | (@now >= time2 >= @last3)")
print(df)
         time1      time2
315 2019-11-12 2018-11-12
316 2019-11-13 2018-11-13
317 2019-11-14 2018-11-14
318 2019-11-15 2018-11-15
319 2019-11-16 2018-11-16
..         ...        ...
736 2021-01-06 2020-01-07
737 2021-01-07 2020-01-08
738 2021-01-08 2020-01-09
739 2021-01-09 2020-01-10
740 2021-01-10 2020-01-11

[153 rows x 2 columns]
```

Another solution without `query` with [`boolean indexing`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#boolean-indexing):

```
df = df[(df.time1 <= pd.to_datetime('now')) & 
        (df.time1 >= pd.to_datetime('now')- pd.DateOffset(months=2))]
```

Comment: It gives me `"timeperiod" is not supported function`

Comment: I edited my question:
I mentioned these function to show what structure I need in my query.

Comment: Actually the main problem is finding `timeperiod()` and `now()` functions.

Comment: I will add some data sample but I have tested `last()' function and it doesn't work because in order to use `last()' function I need to index my data first.

Comment: Beside indexing data I might have multiple columns with datetime type and each of them can be filtered differently,

Comment: I mean last 2 month from now.

Comment: No output is one dataframe that has filtered data. It's like getting data for _plants_ that planted in last 3 month and turned green! in last 2 month. (It's just an example :) )

Comment: @SeyedMohammadHosseini - OK, so please check answer.

Comment: Thank you. The **NOW** part works in `df.query("time <= @pd.to_datetime('now')")` but when I'm trying `df.query("time <= @pd.to_datetime('now') - @pd.DateOffset(months=2)" )` I get `Cannot convert ... ` error. Can you help me?

Comment: As I mentioned I'm trying to create query pattern base on filters and I want to avoid using **Variables** if possible.

Comment: @SeyedMohammadHosseini - I think not possible yet.

Comment: @SeyedMohammadHosseini - Reason is `query` working only for some basic filtering, in answer is more complicated filtering, so failed `df.query("time <= pd.to_datetime('now') - pd.DateOffset(months=2)" )`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205786/discussion-between-jezrael-and-seyed-mohammad-hosseini).